# update function is not called inside my plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a super simple plugin. This is my code:

```
 var methods = {
        init: function (userOptions) {
            console.log('init');

            setInterval(this.update, 1000);
        },

        update: function(){
            console.log(this);
        }
    };

    $.fn.myPlugin = function (methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.myPlugin');
        }
    };
```

Here init is called fine but update is not getting called every 1 seconds. What am I missing here?

Comment: `methods.init.apply(this, arguments)` changes what the value of `this` is. In this case it is set to the jQuery object, which you do not want. You'll want this to refer to methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bound to a jquery object. It has no this.update. May do:

```
setInterval(methods.update.bind(this), 1000);
```

Simply take the update function of the global methods object, and bind the jquery Object to it.

Comment: Isn't bind deprecated as of Jquery 3? Are there other alternatives?

Comment: @timliberty bind has nothing todo with jquery in this context. See Function.prototype.bind for more info...